# How can I intercept the compiler passes

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, cpu-architecture

I would like to make a compiler for a new architecture. I am not sure how big task it is. As far I know Flex/Bison kind tools is free to do several steps of compilation.

**My target is to intercept in Code-Generation pass of compiler**. So, is there any free tool that I can use for my work? Most compilers are embedded with all the different compilation passes.

I am not sure about **LLVM**, but **I need a basic tiny simple compiler where all the different steps is separated**. Probably I will manipulate from **AST** part to **code generation** part.

If you have any idea of a Tool that I can use please suggest.

Comment: Your approach is probably wrong given that you want to "parallelize my code" as you state in a comment. Because even if you find a compiler where you can "intercept code generation", the rest of the compiler most likely still assumes an execution model and a semantics that wont fit with yours.

Comment: If your model of compilation is that "flex/bison do several steps of compilation", your understanding of how compilers work is likely weak enough so you won't succeed at the more complex task of code generation. I suggest you go take a compiler class... which will likely give this opportunity anyway.  If you can't do that, go read a compiler from cover to cover and then reconsider your question.

Comment: yes i have knowledge gap. I told like that based on this article(gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler). Flex/Bison tool used for certain steps like lexical analysis/parsing. But definitely in the back end huge part is done during syntactic analysis to code generationby LLVM like tool. concisely i need a fully functional minimal open source compiler with most important steps separated. so that i can concentrate on my part how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from flex/bison to make a C++ compiler for a new machine is certainly possible but it would be lots of work.  There is lots of semantics analysis code in a compiler that is not covered by flex or bison.

Another choice would be to retarget gcc to your new machine.  But gcc is kind of big and would require lots of research to learn how to change it.  The advantage of gcc is you get c / c++ / java support after your are done retargeting.

I think @ChrisTodd suggestion of lcc is good because there is a book explaining how to retarget the lcc compiler to a new machine.  After you retarget lcc you will only be able to compile C programs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what language you're interested in, but you might want to look at [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) or [lcc](https://sites.google.com/site/lccretargetablecompiler/) if you want a simple C compiler to work with.

Comment: preferably c/c++/Java. in fact i want to parallelize my code as per my new architecture. i was trying to compile SUIF2(NCI-Stanford) which is a program analysis platform but still coudn't able to compile it on ubuntu. I heard of TCC.